# TypeScript: How to import non modular file?

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, es6-modules

I'm using TypeScript. Some of my files are modular using `import` and `export` (I'm using webpack to bundle them), and some are not and I use script tags to add them to the page.

I want to `import` a non modular TypeScript file from a modular one.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

I managed to do it like this:

First in your non modular file add this:

```
if (typeof module !== 'undefined' && module['exports']) {
    module['exports'] = varToExport;
}
```

This will export the file.
Then in your modular file add this to import the file:

```
declare var require;
let moduleToImport;

if (typeof module !== 'undefined' && module['exports']) {
    var moduleToImport = require('./...file address...');
}
```